# How to transfer JDBC request value to REST (POST) request in SOAPUI

Tags: testing, soapui

I am using SOAP UI to perform test with few steps.I need to use a JDBC request's output to use as a input parameter for another REST(POST) request.
Should I use property transfer or a groovy script? Can somebody help ?

Edit:

[image]

From Yellow marked JDBC_Get_Random_Number, a query return a single number
.I need to use it as a input for RegisterCall , which is a REST request(POST)

[image]

JDBC call output should be used as a randNum value. Thanks

Comment: It depends on you. Chose what you are comfortable with. Groovy will have better flexibility, but requires to write the script.

Comment: Provide input data and which value needs to be passed to rest test step. Happy to help. Please update the question for doing so.

Comment: Here is more to clarify!

Comment: Not sure how your jdbc result  going to be, so required for that. screen shot is not really required in this case. or is it that you can use any random number in json with needing to run jdbc step?

Comment: Already solved this problem! these below link help me a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160715/how-could-i-set-value-of-json-object-as-a-request-in-soapui

Comment: @albciff already upvoated !

Comment: @mnhmilu thanks `:P`